# Add string to page url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For example this is the original link.
http://localhost/myhouse/homes-for-sale-details/6200-SAN-VICENTE-BOULEVARD-LOS-ANGELES-CA-90048/OC16023911/306/

I want to add "sold" on that "/homes-for-sale-details/" url.

So it will look like this and needs to go this link.
http://localhost/myhouse/homes-for-sale-sold-details/6200-SAN-VICENTE-BOULEVARD-LOS-ANGELES-CA-90048/OC16023911/306/

part of the URL will be linke this with the "sold" word:
/homes-for-sale-sold-details/

Comment: `url = url.replace("homes-for-sale-details", "homes-for-sale-sold-details");` [Check online](https://jsfiddle.net/zxddkxfc/)

Comment: yes I know that we can use replace.
but I want it to be dynamic.

I will not use it for this link only:
http://localhost/myhouse/homes-for-sale-sold-details/6200-SAN-VICENTE-BOULEVARD-LOS-ANGELES-CA-90048/OC16023911/306/

I will use it on many different link such as this one too:
http://localhost/nikkibascon/homes-for-sale-details/4344-CORDERO-DRIVE-EL-DORADO-HILLS-CA-95762/16007845/

Thank's :)

Comment: so what?? your `homes-for-sale-details` is a common string and the replace function just replace this.

Comment: how about can we just get the URL and put it into a variable?

Comment: add your simple urls....to your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
// store url in variable
url = 'http://localhost/myhouse/homes-for-sale-details/6200-SAN-VICENTE-BOULEVARD-LOS-ANGELES-CA-90048/OC16023911/306/';

// get url with replace 
new_url = url.replace("homes-for-sale-details", "homes-for-sale-sold-details");
```

Comment: yes I know that we can use replace.
but I want it to be dynamic.

I will not use it for this link only:
http://localhost/myhouse/homes-for-sale-sold-details/6200-SAN-VICENTE-BOULEVARD-LOS-ANGELES-CA-90048/OC16023911/306/

I will use it on many different link such as this one too:
http://localhost/nikkibascon/homes-for-sale-details/4344-CORDERO-DRIVE-EL-DORADO-HILLS-CA-95762/16007845/

Thank's :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// store url in variable
$url = 'http://localhost/myhouse/homes-for-sale-details/6200-SAN-VICENTE-BOULEVARD-LOS-ANGELES-CA-90048/OC16023911/306/';

echo str_replace("homes-for-sale-details","homes-for-sale-sold-details",$url);
```

Use this code it will work.

Comment: yes I know that we can use replace.
but I want it to be dynamic.

I will not use it for this link only:
http://localhost/myhouse/homes-for-sale-sold-details/6200-SAN-VICENTE-BOULEVARD-LOS-ANGELES-CA-90048/OC16023911/306/

I will use it on many different link such as this one too:
http://localhost/nikkibascon/homes-for-sale-details/4344-CORDERO-DRIVE-EL-DORADO-HILLS-CA-95762/16007845/

Thank's :)